# What are the debug tools that i can use for GUI Automation on Internet Explorer?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css

Are there any tools similar to firebug/firepath that i can use to test the locators on the internet explorer browser? 
I was running an xpath which works in firefox but fails in IE.

Comment: if u know how to create xpath(Absolute and relative) for the element then there is no need to for any tool, i recommend you to learn creating xpath

Comment: Take a look at this SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351/is-there-something-like-firebug-for-ie-for-debugging-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the IE developer tools (F12)?

Comment: Hi Sperk, I've had a number of notes on this that it doesn't answer the question. Could you elaborate? (Not having done much with IE, I'm not sure if it answers the question or not.)